# Spring Integration @ServiceActivator Message Handler doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Why testOutputHandler() doesn't print anything? It seems that alarmHandler() doesn't push message to outputChannel = "testOutput"

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = CHANNEL_ALARM, requiresReply = "true", outputChannel = "testOutput")
public MessageHandler alarmHandler(SessionFactory<FTPFile> sessionFactory) {
    return message -> {
        System.out.println(CHANNEL_ALARM);
        System.out.println(message.getHeaders());
        };
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "testOutput" )
public MessageHandler testOutputHandler() {
    return message -> {
        System.out.println("test");
        System.out.println(message.getHeaders());
    };
}
```

Here is console output, we can see that alarmHandler does its work, but testOutput doesn't

```
 2022-10-04 17:56:53.710  INFO 26092 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherApplicationRunner   : Running default command line with: []
alarm
{file_remoteHostPort=192.168.1.44:21, file_remoteFileInfo={"directory":false,"filename":"Alarm_Logs_12.9.2022_0.41.csv","link":false,"modified":1664782140000,"permissions":"----------","remoteDirectory":"for_it","size":88804}, file_remoteDirectory=for_it, channel=alarm, id=67d21ff6-e0ef-1992-2b32-ab759a8c1076, closeableResource=org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession@4b9ffb22, file_remoteFile=Alarm_Logs_12.9.2022_0.41.csv, timestamp=1664884618273}
```

Comment: And it should becuase? Your `alarmHandler` doesn't return anything so there is nothing to process.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right, thank you! It is better choice to use handlers as part of POJO rather than Configuration where possible for clear understanding  EIP pipe-filter principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MessageHandler` you use in your `alarmHandler()` bean definition has a contract like this:

```
void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException;
```

Indeed it does not produce anything to the `outputChannel` since its return type is `void`.

Not sure what is your expectations since you definitely placed yourself to that corner.

Top make it send to the `testOutput` you must change your method signature like this, for example:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = CHANNEL_ALARM, requiresReply = "true", outputChannel = "testOutput")
public Strung alarmHandler(Message<?> message) {
        System.out.println(CHANNEL_ALARM);
        System.out.println(message.getHeaders());
      return "foo";
}
```